# Dudas al diseñar unas tablas relacionadas entre si

Tags: mysql, sql, relaciones, tsql

Estoy teniendo problemas para identificar una relación en una base de datos SQL, no estoy seguro si es una relación `uno a muchos` ó `muchos a muchos`. (me inclino mas a una relación de `muchos a muchos` pero la duda no me la puedo sacar de la cabeza)

De verdad me cuesta un poco lograr identificar una relación `1 a muchos` ó `muchos a muchos`

Antes de tirar una linea de codigo, yo estoy plasmando la representación de mis tablas en excel para poder visualizar mejor.

La funcion es poder realizar un inventario de activos que se encuentran en cada sucursal para poder llevar el control de los mismos y saber cuantos se tienen en cada sucursal.

Tengo las siguientes tablas `masters`

**Inventario**

Almacena el nombre de cada inventario que se de haga.

| id | nombre del inventario |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sucursal A |
| 2 | Sucursal B |
| 3 | Sucursal C |
| 3 | Sucursal E cierre de año |
| 4 | Sucursal F Eliminacion de esta sucursal |

**Activos**

Almacena todos los activos que existan en todas las sucursales

| id | nombre del activo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Samsung Galaxy S10 |
| 2 | Samsung Galaxy S11 |
| 3 | Samsung Galaxy S12 |
| 4 | Laptop HP 15" |
| 5 | Laptop Asus 15" |
| 6 | Laptop Mac 15" |
| 7 | Televisor 20" |
| 8 | Televisor 40" |
| 9 | Televisor 60" |

Aquí tendria que crear una tabla intermedia verdad? que este compuesta con los pk de cada tabla

ejemplo de unos inserts

**inventarioXactivo**

| id | id_inventario | id_activofijo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 4 |
| 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 8 |
| 9 | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 | 6 |
| 11 | 2 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 | 9 |

En teoría quedaria así?

**En la Sucursal 1 existen:**

cantidad   -   activo

- (3) Samsung Galaxy S10
- (2) Samsung Galaxy S11
- (1) Laptop HP 15"
- (1) Laptop Asus 15"

**En la Sucursal 2 existen:**

- (1) Televisor 40"
- (1) Samsung Galaxy S11
- (1) Laptop Mac 15"
- (1) Samsung Galaxy S10
- (1) Televisor 60"

Estoy en lo correcto? ó el diseño de las tablas que acabo de hacer estan mall? por favor necesito orientación o que me corrijan.

Comment: Aquello que no quieres hacer, que es tirar código, debes de hacerlo, sólo así estarás seguro si es correcto o no lo que ya pensaste. Después de eso puedes venir aquí y plasmar tus dudas.

Comment: @RodrigoCortés no es que no quiera tirar código, es que no sé si lo esté haciendo bien por ese motivo es mi duda. Está mal hacer este tipo de publicación? si es asi la borraré

Comment: @I'mnewbie, diría que es correcto lo que planteas como resultado. Pero no queda claro cual es el problema. ¿Por qué crees que esta mal tu diseño?

Comment: Como dice el compañero @Marcos, tu diseño está bien. Recuerda que siempre que sea una relación de muchos a muchos, es mejor (y más conveniente) tener una tabla intermediaria, en dónde van sobre todo los detalles que unen a las dos tablas.

Comment: Imagina que tuvieras que almacenar el número de serie de los equipos, ¿Dónde lo guardarías?.

Comment: @Sal Interesante pregunta, tengo un buen rato analizando , yo creo que lo mejor seria crear una tabla llamada `activo_detalle` donde tendria como propieades su `pk auto incremental` , serial del equipo, precio del equipo(el costo de compra), ubicacion del equipo ( sala de reuniones, cuarto de servidores etc.. dentro de la sucursal) etren otros campos, su llave foranea seria la pk de la tabla `activo` esto deberia ser una relacion de uno a muchos ( uno activo - muchos activo_detalle)  estoy plasmando una buena solucion a tu pregunta? y Gracias por plantearme esta pregunta!!

Answer (score 0):

si quieres saber cuantos productos o activos se tienen en cada sucursal, creo que la mejor manera seria la relacion de 1 a muchos, ya que segun san google dice 'un registro de una tabla se puede asociar a uno o varios registros de otra tabla.' esto quiere decir que si haces una consulta de activos en una sucursal especifica te saldran todos los activos disponibles. Sin embargo tambien puede que pueda ser una relacion de muchos a muchos, aplicando un ejemplo de que quieras que se aplique lo de arriba y tambien de saber en que sucursal/sucursalees estan ciertos activos. A mi parecer en la tabla intermedia deberian ir los id de las sucursales o sus nombres y el inventario de los activos actualizados y el inventario por cada mes(segun sea el abastecimiento) para llevar control de que se ha introducido, mi pura opinion.